# vuejs the props is called before it is available they are available only on click

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

vuejs the props is called before it is available they are available only on click
I have an error Cannot read property 'name' of undefined because it cannot find name because the data is sent to the click in a modal Ex: :fanInfo="fanInfo"

Button seed data item.fan

```
  @click="() => {
                     obj.item.name === 'cell' && Object.keys(item.fan).length
                              ? modalCellOpen(item.fan)
                              : '';
                          }
```

Method Function

```
modalCellOpen(obj) {
      this.isLoading = true;
      this.fanInfo = obj;
      this.modalStore.showModal('cell');
      this.isLoading = false;
      console.log(obj);
    },
```

Components

```
<AddCell :fanInfo="fanInfo" />
```

I get an object if I click on the modal it shows me object if I put {{cellInfo}} to it, but if I put {{cellInfo.name}} I have an error Cannot read property 'name' of undefined how to do so that it only loads the data when you click and not before ?

```
"stored_species": {
    "id": 7,
    "name": "toto",
    "feature": null,
    "color": "#aac284",
  }
```

Comment: your question is not clear and broken. Pleas, if you can write your whole/minimum vue file in order to best describe your scenario.

Comment: Try [Conditional Rendering](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/conditional.html#conditional-rendering)